# how to fix required Long found Long?

Tags: kotlin

i am trying to add two number whose type is Long

```
@Entity
data class Monitor(
        @PrimaryKey
        @NonNls
        var parentUsageDuration: Long? = 0L,
        var childUsageDuration: Long ?= 0L
)
```

there is two number

```
var parentTime = homeViewModel.getMonitorAllDataItem()?.parentUsageDuration
var childTime =  homeViewModel.getMonitorAllDataItem()?.childUsageDuration
```

when i try to add this two number

```
 var totalTime =  parentTime +childTime
```

I am getting error

```
required Long found Long ?
```

unable to add this two number please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that `parentTime` and `childTime` numbers are not just numbers. They are numbers or nulls - notice `?` char in `Long?`. It is not possible to perform math operations on nulls, so we need to decide what do to in the case of nulls. Most common solutions are:

Set `totalTime` to null if at least one of numbers is null:

```kotlin
var totalTime = if (parentTime == null || childTime == null) null else parentTime + childTime
```

Replace nulls with some defaults, e.g. `0`:

```kotlin
var totalTime = (parentTime ?: 0) + (childTime ?: 0)
```

Or, if we are sure that in fact these values can't be null:

```kotlin
var totalTime = parentTime!! + childTime!!
```

If this is the case then you should also consider changing the type of `parentUsageDuration` and `childUsageDuration` to not-nullable `Long`, but it really depends on your specific case.

Answer (score -1):

`parentTime` and `childTime` have type `Long?` while `totalTime` has type `Long`.
You can fix it via changing type. Like

```
var parentTime:Long = homeViewModel.getMonitorAllDataItem()?.parentUsageDuration!!
```

Comment: do we need to use !! ??

Comment: its giving me null Pointer exception

Comment: @MARSH that means the value is null. If you want a fallback value for in case it's null you could for example do this instead: `homeViewModel.getMonitorAllDataItem()?.parentUsageDuration ?: 0L`